# SQLite to emulate an extensive file system structure?

Tags: database, algorithm, sqlite, filesystems

I need to implement a sort of a local persistent storage system (simply speaking - on disk). There should be (virtual) **folders** and **files**.

Each folder has a unique fixed-size ID, and the expected number of folders is pretty high, can reach **millions**, and the system should sustain this without dramatic degradation. Each folder contains limited number of files (~tens) of arbitrary size. Mostly small, but some may reach order of several MBs.

Worth to add also that the system will work mostly with the recent folders. The probability of the need in older folders is lower.

Now, I need to design and implement this. A very naive approach is to implement such a system "literally", using the file system with flat hierarchy. But it's not practical in the long run, since the file system directory is actually an object, which is rewritten whenever you add/remove something to the directory. So that creating a sub-directory whereas millions already exist - is obviously a bad idea.

A better solution would be arranging all the folders in some hierarchy (for example a radix-style, where the first few bits of the directory name define the 1st subfolder, next few bits define the next subfolder, and so on.

But there is also an option to store all the data in the DB, such as SQLite (I had a good experience with it in the past). With proper indexes it should be faster than just file system (i.e. looking for a specific file/subfolder). And I also like the ability of modifications in a transaction-mode (though I can also live without this).

So far the DB option looks superior. But it seems to have a drawback too. It's related to the fact that the relational DB structure is **flat**. Means, when I need to access a specific object (file) - basically the entire DB is searched. I can't isolate some specific subfolder. For instance accessing several files in the same directory will inevitably lead to the search through all the files of this type (assuming there's a separate table for them) for every such a file, though they all "live" in the same directory.

So, my question is: does it sound like a significant drawback vs file system (which **is** hierarchical)?

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think so. I think a database would be both faster and easier to implement and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> With proper indexes it should be faster than just file system

and:

> when I need to access a specific object (file) - basically the entire DB is searched. I can't isolate some specific subfolder.

These statements contradict each other. With proper indexes, all queries are efficient.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE FileSystem (
    ID        INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    ParentDir INTEGER REFERENCES FileSystem(ID),
    Name      TEXT,
    Data      BLOB  -- NULL for directories
);
CREATE INDEX DirNameLookup ON FileSystem(ParentDir, Name);
```

Reading a file named `a/b/c` uses these queries, all of which can go through the `DirNameLookup` index:

```
SELECT ID   FROM FileSystem WHERE ParentDir IS NULL AND Name = 'a';
SELECT ID   FROM FileSystem WHERE ParentDir = ?     AND Name = 'b';
SELECT Data FROM FileSystem WHERE ParentDir = ?     AND Name = 'c';
```

(Instead of using IS NULL for the root directory, you could also create a row with a known ID, e.g., `0` or `1`.)

Comment: I meant, DB is very efficient when you need to search "from scratch". But it may be less efficient (IMHO) than hierarchical structure, when you need to access an object whereas you already "found" its parent.

Comment: What do you mean with "found"? That you have its ID?

Comment: It can be anything, applicable to the specific hierarchical structure: an open directory object containing file system references to the contained files, or whatever. Anyway, my point is that **any** hierarchical structure allows to search within a specific scope only. Whereas relational DBs by definition are "flat".

Comment: When you have the ID of a directory, you can start searching there. You appear to misunderstand how indexed lookups work.

Comment: Maybe I actually misunderstand this. Indexes give you access with logarithmic complexity, not O(1) (like direct pointers). In the example that you provide all 3 queries will work in O(log(N)), whereas N is the overall size of the table. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, it's log(N) (with a very small constant factor because DB pages are large, and cached). How is that different from a file system, or any other data structure?

Comment: In a hierarchical system you pay O(log(N)) to find the directory. Then, within the directory that you found, you pay O(1) to access the file that you need. Think of it as a search map of directories, whereas each directory contains an array of (pointers to) files, accessing an element in an array is O(1).

Comment: And how do you keep a reference to a directory in the file system? (If file system accesses were as fast as you think, databases would store rows as files.)

Comment: Just think of it as objects in memory with pointers. Speaking conceptually, the even fact if it's in the physical RAM or on the disk is not important.